# Basic Public/Private function structure in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript. I want to implement recursion using two functions: one public, another private.

In Java, I'd always implement recursion like this

```
public int sumOfPrevious(int n){
 return addNumbers(n);
}

private int addNumbers(int n){
 if (n == 1)
  return 1;
 else
  return n + addNumbers(n-1);
}
```

Then calling **System.out.println(sumOfPrevious(5))** returns 15

But how do you implement something like that in JavaScript?

I tried this:

```
function sumOfPrevious(n){
 return function privateFunc(n){
  if (n == 1)
    return 1;
  else
    return n + privateFunc(n - 1);
  };
}
```

But calling **console.log(sumOfPrevious(5))** just gives me **[Function: privateFunc]**

Why is it doing that and how do I fix this?

Comment: You need to invoke the function

Comment: A working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4g83V/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning the defined function itself.

Simply execute it :

```
function sumOfPrevious(n){
 return (function privateFunc(n){
  if (n == 1)
    return 1;
  else
    return n + privateFunc(n - 1);
  })(n);
}
```

A working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4g83V/) at jsfiddle.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

You need to declare the nested function and then use it, not return the nested function.

```
function sumOfPrevious(n){
  function privateFunc(n){
    if (n == 1)
      return 1;
    else
      return n + privateFunc(n - 1);
  }
  return privateFunc(n);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You return a function so you get a function...

To define private function you must create a class, as you do in Java, and then make the magic inside

```
function MyClass() {
    var idx = this;
    var my_private_member = 5;
    this.my_public_member = 0;

    function my_private_function() {
        idx.my_public_member = my_private_member; //keyword "this" here won't reference to MyClass, but to the private function, so we keep a reference of MyClass to be accessed by the private function
    }
    this.my_public_function = function() {
        my_private_function();
    }
}

var my_instance = new MyClass();
```

`my_private_member` and `my_private_function` can't be accessed

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a function for recursion:

JAVA and Javascript are two totally different things.

```
function sumOfPrevious(n){
  if (n == 1)
    return 1;
  else
    return n + sumOfPrevious(n - 1);
}

// call the function
console.log(sumOfPrevious(10)); // 55
```